# Excel: conflict between validation, protection, and worksheet_beforeDoubleClick

Tags: validation, vba, excel

I'm trying to build a protected worksheet where one of the cells has the following qualities:

1. Double-clicking the cell populates it with "hello".
2. The cell can only be blank or contain the word "hello".

So I decided to put validation on the cell, and write a `worksheet_beforeDoubleClick()` event.

Let's say it's cell A1.  Starting with a blank worksheet, in B1 I enter "hello", and I set A1's validation as a list with range B1:B2.

My double-click event code is as follows:

```
Private Sub worksheet_beforedoubleclick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column = 1 Then
    Target.Value = "hello"
End If

End Sub
```

This code and validation works fine while the sheet is unprotected; the cell populates with "hello" when double-clicked.

However, once the sheet is protected, double-clicking on cell A1 turns the mouse pointer into an hourglass until I press Esc or click on another cell; the cell does not populate with the word "hello".

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you protect the sheet, check the "Edit Objects" checkbox and it will work.  Don't know quite why, but it will.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Doug for a lead in the right direction. For future reference, a good VBA snippet for this is:

```
ActiveSheet.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True, DrawingObjects:=False
```

This will protect the sheet, but allow macros to edit the sheet, as well as clear up the conflict described here.

Answer (score 1):

While the answers above with unprotecting the drawing objects works, the end solution with respect to the user being able to right click and edit drawing object shapes is not always acceptable.

My work around was to use a checkbox to the left of the cell and add a macro that did what my double click action originally was doing.